# How to get the file paths of all files that are created between two QDatetime's in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on a Qt (C++) application which fetches files from a server. All incoming files are created according to the following format

> "yyyyMMddHHmmss.[6 random characters].[RANDOM TEXT WITH RANDOM LENGTH].dcm"

e.g. "20151214235923.blabla.bla.dcm"

The application stores two `QDateTime` variables: `sessionBeginDateTime` (format: yyyyMMddHHmmss) and `sessionEndDateTime` (format: yyyyMMddHHmmss).

I would like to know how I can get the file paths of all files (in a directory) that are created between the `sessionBeginDateTime` and `sessionEndDateTime`.

My code to get all file paths from the directory:

```
QDirIterator it(dir, QStringList() << "*.dcm", QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
while (it.hasNext()) {
    //do something...
}
```

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#created gives you the creation date of the file. The rest of the logic should be trivial, or where exactly is your problem?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld You are awesome! I never ever thought about this solution xD

Comment: Ehm, "application which fetches files from a server”, QFileInfo::created won’t work then I guess, because it will give you the local creation date. You’ll actually have to cut the filename into chunks and use QDateTime::fromString() on the timestamp string.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Normally yes, but in my case the incoming files are are created by my application. So your first comment's solution is perfectly fine! I am so stupid I could think of that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Frank Osterfeld's answer is the right answer:**

"doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#created gives you the creation date of the file."